# Is it possible to create a VM on Linux then export it to a Windows Server?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, vmware, virtualization, system-administration

I'm trying to install and configure some apps in VM in Windows Server but have a limited access to the Windows server so I'm trying to do all the configuration in a local VM in my Ubuntu system then export the VM to the server. Is it possible?

Comment: As long as a compatible VM "player" is used in both environments it should work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most virtualization systems can handle [OVF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Virtualization_Format) format. You can create VM on VirualBox, save it to OVF (or OVA) and then restore it in VMWare ESXi environment, for example. OVF contains a "hard drive" data and all virtual hardware info. But OVF [is not fully compatible with Microsoft Hyper-V](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj158932.aspx). There are some tools that allows OVF file to be converted into Hyper-V compatible form, but all the hardware information will be lost.